# LDAP and User root/sudo on local netboot ubuntu/debian machine

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, sudo, root, netboot

I'd like to create a debian/ubuntu pxe netboot image authenticating against ldap but I want give the user the power to install software on his local machine.

In Windows I simply add a local admin account and give the user the according credentials, maybe that's also wrong - but especially in debian/ubuntu environment I expect users with sudo can use `su` to be whoever they want to be - even a more privileged central admin.

Is there a gallant way to solve this issue?

Maybe I need more wisdom by searching certain words on google you can provide?

I know it's several concepts colliding but understanding why for me is essential.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: doing research: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94585/difference-between-windows-local-admin-and-unix-root

Comment: installing packages without sudo: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42567/how-to-install-program-locally-without-sudo-privileges